# Image view not showing

Tags: java, android, android-imageview

I have a code which adds buttons and images dynamically to a fragment. The buttons are getting added but the images are not being added.

Here is my code :

```
for(String f1 : f){

    // For Each File Add a View or a button or something
    LogUtil.d(TAG,"ocr override" + f1);

    Button b = new Button (getActivity());
    b.setId (i);
    b.setLayoutParams(params2);
    b.setText (f1);
    b.setOnClickListener(this);

    ImageView img_view = new ImageView(getContext());

    img_view.setImageBitmap(getBitmapFromAsset("OcrSampleImages"+System.getProperty("file.separator")+f1));
    img_view.setLayoutParams(params);

    linearLayout.addView(b);
    linearLayout.addView(img_view,params);

    i++;
}
```

params and params2 are defined as follows :

```
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

LayoutParams params2 = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

**Here is the output on the emulator :**

**Here is my assets folder :**

Comment: Can you post your `getBitmapFromAsset(String)` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better to use iterative strategy..

first, `new ImageView(getContext());`  -> `new ImageView(**getActivity()**);`

Secondly, if you don't know where is the problem, then better reading default drawable image

```
img_view.setImageResource(R.drawable.<any_dummy_image_from_drawable>);
```

instead of

```
setImageBitmap()
```

if your dummy image load properly that means your View is perfect and **having problem while reading from assets**, 
If so, then you can **concentrate more on asset reading thing**.

Comment: I tried adding an image from R.drawable and it worked....so what might be the problem with setImageBitmap() ?

Comment: "OcrSampleImages"+System.getProperty("file.separator")+f1

may not be present,
for asset directory structure,
assets/image/abc.jpg 

sample code would be 

    AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();

        InputStream istr;
         Bitmap bitmap = null;
        try {
             istr = assetManager.open("image/abc.jpg");
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istr);
         } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
         }

          return bitmap;

Comment: what is the problem with that line ?

Comment: better print "OcrSampleImages"+System.getProperty("file.separator")+f1 

in Logs to check whether its correct or not.. that will help you to debug by yourself..
and as a practice..(don't know its required or not),
**Try using lowercase letters in asset's folder and file names.**